# Windows 8 Multi-touch image control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8

I have an image in win8 app. (c#, xaml) 
I need to zoom and rotate image using multi-touch.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx

Read the docs in MSDN. They are very good.